# При попадании текста в определенный div убирать все HTML теги и символ абзаца

Tags: javascript, php

Есть сайт на WordPress. Есть `div class="text"` в него пользователи вставляют текст (ctrl+v), но предварительно они могут скопировать в буфер обмена текст с HTMl тегами и символами абзаца. Можно ли при как то автоматически чистить текст от HTMl тегов и символа абзаца при вставке текста в `div class="text"`?

Answer (score 0):

Можно классически с помощью JavaScript:

```js
var s = "<p>Ваш текст в параграфе.</p>";
s = s.replace(/<\/?[a-zA-Z]+>/gi,'');
alert(s); // Ваша строка, но без тегов
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А как привязаться к классу div? И будет ли убирать вместе с тегами абзацы?

Comment: $('div.text').each(function(){
    // Работа над каждым элементом выборки по вашему вкусу
});

Comment: javascript можно отключить на стороне клиента или поправить код - и тогда html-теги все равно будут приходить. я бы рекомендовал использовать после submit функцию php - strip_tags https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strip-tags